# Symfony2 Form ChoiceType External Datasource

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form class with several ChoiceType fields that contain an array of options with a key:value pair. When the form is submitted the value is saved. However when I'm rendering the object I would like to show the Key value instead.

Example: 'Monthly' => '1month'. 1month is stored, prefer output to be Monthly.

I'm trying to avoid conditionals to check the value and changing the output to the key value.

I wasn't able to find any documentation about best practices for this sort of thing. I'm thinking about creating a service that stores all the choice options arrays and build a twig filter for changing the rendered output based on the array from the service.

Am I on the right track or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create enumerator class and use it in your template, like so:

```
class MyChoicesEnum {

private static $choices = array(
                      'Monthly' => '1month',
                      'Quarterly' => '4month',
                      // etc... 
            );

  public static function choices() {
      return self::$choices;
  }


}
```

Then you pass the class method result to template, in the returned array:

```
...
'form' => $form->createView()
'my_choices' => MyChoicesEnum::choices()
```

And in twig:

```
{{ my_choices.key }}
```

Comment: When the form is submitted, I store the object into a session variable and I can see via a dump() of that session variable that #fullPayment: "2weeks", #compounding: "daily" are being saved with the value not the key. That's with the choices array being ('Monthly' => '1month', 'Bi-weekly' => '2weeks') etc

Comment: You are right. I checked the docs, it has been changed in recent versions: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values

Answer (score 0):

I tried the service solution and got it working. I'm not sure if it is the most elegant or efficient way but it did the job. The form was a form class type and I injected a service that contained the choice arrays.

I created a choices.php class file inside my Form folder next to the formType file. It acts as a service where it returns the choices to the formType and a custom twig extension filter I created. The formType I had to set up as a service in order to inject the choices service.

```
/*choices.php*/
public function getChoices($choice)
{
    $choices = array('paymentFrequency' => array('Monthly' => '1month',
                                                 'Bi-weekly' => '2weeks'),
                     'compounding' => array('Monthly' => 'monthly',
                                            'Daily' => 'daily')
    );

    return $choices[$choice];
}

/*formType.php*/
->add('paymentFrequency', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Payment Frequency:',
            'choices' => $this->choicesService->getChoices('paymentFrequency'),
 ))
->add('compounding', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Compounding:',
            'choices' => $this->choicesService->getChoices('compounding'),
 ))
```

I then created a custom twig filter function where the choices service is injected into it.

```
/*twigExtension.php*/
public function renderChoicesFilter($value, $type)
{

    $choices = $this->choicesService->getChoices($type);

    return array_search($value, $choices);
}

/*twig template*/
{{ object.paymentFrequency|renderChoices('paymentFrequency') }}
```